# Can an svmlight model be converted to work with libsvm?

Tags: svm, libsvm

I have a model file that was created using svmlight in classification mode with a linear kernel. Is it possible to convert this file so that libsvm can use it for classifying?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to retrain it. For the training file, in the svmlight / libsvm format, each line takes the form [(source)](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/datasets/index.html#datasets-in-svmlight-libsvm-format) :

```
<label> <feature-id>:<feature-value> <feature-id>:<feature-value> ....
```